# Calling a function of a child from another child Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to call the methods that a child component has from another component that is a child of the same parent but at a lower level. Seen schematically:

```
            |--Child B
 Father A---|
            |--Child C---|--Child D
```

A is the father of everyone and it has two childrens, B and C. C is the father of D too.

In my application of Angular, component B has an instance of a map and functions to manage that map. C is a router component that changes D component depending on the application.

**Component A**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

**HTML of Component A**

```
<ng-container>
   <mat-sidenav-container> 
      <mat-sidenav>
         <!--Component C-->
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content >
        <!--Component B-->
        <app-map></app-map>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
   </mat-sidenav-container>
</ng-container>
```

**Component B**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})


    export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
      ngOnInit(){...}
      drawWMSLayer(layerName:string){...}
      deleteWMSLayer(){...}
      drawCoordinates(coordinates:any){...}
      obtainIDENAMap(){...}
      //......//
    }
```

**HTML of component B**

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div> <!--Openlayers map-->
```

**Component C**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/inicio', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'inicio', component: PaginaInicioComponent },
  { path: 'edificios', component: EdificiosComponent },
  { path: 'parkings', component: ParkingsComponent },
  //..........//
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Component D is changed by the router** (one of them)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edificios',
  templateUrl: './edificios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edificios.component.css']
})
export class EdificiosComponent implements OnInit {
  //........//
 /* I would like to call MapComponent functions from here */
}
```

Component B is always the same, and it only modifies the values of its attributes through its functions.

It is a "Google Maps type" application in which the map is the same and it changes its appearance according which of its functions you call.

Comment: Hi. Can you tell which component has to call which component's method?
I.e. B should call D's method etc.

Comment: D component should call B's methods. Component D will be changed by the AppRoutingModule, but all the components that would be placed there, will call B's methods

Answer (score 0):

Since this is following a different set of hierarchy, and things can be further nested too, I'd suggest using a service to handle the cases.

```js
class MyMapService {
  methodCallSource = new BehaviorSubject<{method: string, params: any}>(null);
  methodCall$: Observable<{method: string, params: any}>;

  constructor() {
    this.methodCall$ = this.methodCallSource.asObservable();
  }
}
```

```js
class ComponentB {
  mapMethodCallSub;
  constructor () {
    private myMapService: MyMapService
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapMethodCallSub = this.myMapService.methodCall$
      .subscribe((callArgs) => {
        const {method, params} = callArgs;
        switch(method) {
          case 'doSomething':
            this.doSomething(params);
            break;
          case 'doSomethingElse':
            this.doSomething(params);
            break;
        }
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mapMethodCallSub.unsubscribe();
  }
  doSomething({param1}) { // keep your params as objects

  }
  doSomethingElse({param1, param2}) { // keep your params as objects

  }
}
```

```js
class ComponentD {
  constructor () {
    private myMapService: MyMapService
  }

  someTrigger() {
    this.myMapService.methodCallSource.next('doSomething', {param1: 'Ahsan'});
  }

  someActionTest() {
    this.myMapService.methodCallSource.next('doSomethingElse', {param1: 'Satellite', param2: 'Texas'});
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, looks interesting. I've tried that solution but I obtain an error in Component B while while calling `this.myMapService.methodCall$()`. "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Observable<{ method: string; params: any; }>' has no compatible call signatures". Do you know the problem?